# Are injective continuous functions on open sets open?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a continuous injective function $f$ from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is not open?

Comment: I guess since someone downvoted, I'll explain that I think this is true in R, but I don't know it for larger n, this is true if stronger constraints than continuity is placed

Comment: A map into its image is onto, so you have a continuous injective and surjective function into its image. Continuity implies that if $f(U)$ is open, then $f^{-1}f(U) = U$ is open.

Comment: I don't understand how what you said relates to the question asked, can you elaborate?

Comment: Aren't you asking if there is a continuous injective $f: U \to f(U)$ such that $f(U)$ is not open?

Comment: Yes both domain and domain in $R^n$, otherwise this is clearly false, for example if f maps from $R$ to $R^2$.

Comment: I mean if $f = Id$, and you take any closed set like $[a,b]$, the image is closed.

Comment: Why has question been closed? Brouwer obviously thought the subject was "on-topic" when he solved it in 1912. How does it "not meet MSE guidelines"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The injective continuous image of an open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always open - this is a consequence of [**invariance of domain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: I knew this was familiar.

Comment: Isn't the connected open set, not only open set?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad I don't understand what you're asking - yes, there are disconnected open sets, but that doesn't affect anything here. (That said, looking back I just realized I forgot to include the word "injective" - the OP includes it, but if looked at out of context my answer could be misleading, so I've fixed it.)

Comment: No, what am I telling is that the theorem is true if the open set is connected, which is basically stated when we are telling it is as a domain.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad There is no connectedness hypothesis anywhere. [Invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) states simply that if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $U$ and $ran(f)$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Got it.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad Are you thinking of [Open mapping theorem (complex analysis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))?

Comment: No, that is clear now.