# Continuous injection from reals to circle is open map

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to S^1$ be continuous injective function (where $S^1$ is unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$). How to show that $f(a,b)$ is open for any $(a,b)\in \Bbb R$ where $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$ are possibilities?

I went like this: Maybe, we can consider $f$ as function from $\Bbb R\to [c,d)$, then it is strict monotone (since continuous and injective), then I can prove that $f(a,b)$ open.

But, I can't justify why considering $f$ as function from $\Bbb R\to [c,d)$ is

(Is there any direct approach to show that for $f:\Bbb R\to S^1$, f(a,b) is open?)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065463/42969

Comment: There is no continuous monotone function from $\mathbb R$ to $[c,d)$.

Comment: Hint: There exists a continuous map $\theta:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $f(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How do you prove the existence of such a continuous function? I guess you first show that a whole open arc is not contained in the image of $f$ and then use a branch of the logarithm?

Comment: @amsmath You could use the fact that $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is a covering map. Or do it by hand: wlog $f(0)=1$. Let $A$ be the sup of the $k>0$ such that there exists $\theta:[0,k]\to\Bbb R$ with $\theta(0)=0$ and $f(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$ for all $t\in[0,k]$. Show that $A=\infty$, because if $A<\infty$ then  you can actually extend $\theta$ to $[0,A+\delta]$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But how would you know that your $\theta$ is continuous? I would prefer choosing a point $z\in\mathbb T$ which is not in the image of $f$, then choose a branch cut from zero through this point and denote the corresponding logarithm by $\log$. Then I would define $\theta(t):=-i\log(f(t))$.

Comment: @amsmath My comment wasn't supposed to be a formal proof. "...such that there exists $\theta$..." was (I thought clearly) supposed to mean "...such that there exists a continuous $\theta$...". Yes, of course saying $\theta(t)=-i\log(f(t))$ is exactly one way to define $\theta$ _locally_ - the point then is it's possible to patch those local thetas together into a global one.

Comment: @amsmath Details in new Answer...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In the present case ($f$ is injective) I can define $\theta(t) = -i\log(f(t))$ globally, so for each $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, you can do that, since curiously here injective implies not surjective. (That seems "wrong" to me, since it gives the impression that injectivity is somehow needed; in fact the fact that $\theta$ exists for  a general continuous $f$ is fundmental and not that hard...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, you're right. I guess that assumption just makes it easier to prove the statement for people with less knowledge (like me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can do this from scratch, without using covering maps or invoking invariance of domain: Let $(a,b)$ be a basis element for $\tau_{\mathbb R}$. Then, because $f$ is injective, $f((a,b))$ can not be onto $S^1.$ And then, since $f$ is continuous, and $(a,b)$ is connected, $f((a,b))$ is either an open, a half-open, or a closed arc. If the arc is open, we are done. If not, without loss of generality it is of the form $(zw]; z,w\in S^1.$ Now, let $(w-\epsilon,w+\epsilon)$ be an open arc containing $w$. There is a $a<c<b$ and a $\delta>0$ such that $f(c)=w,\ (c-\delta,c+\delta)\subseteq (a,b)$ and $f((c-\delta,c+\delta))\subseteq (w-\epsilon,w].$ But, $(c-\delta,c]$ and $(c,c+\delta)$ must be mapped by $f$ into disjoint arcs contained in $(w-\epsilon,w].$ But then, we get a contradiction because $f(c)\neq w:$ if so then there is an $\eta>0$ such that $f((c-\delta,c))\subseteq (\eta,w]$ such that $f(c)=w$ and $f((c,c+\delta)\subseteq (\epsilon_1,\eta)$ so $f$ is not continuous at $c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this awesome proof! Just in last lines, how do you derive that $(c-\delta,c]$ and $(c,c+\delta)$ must be mapped by $f$ into disjoint arcs contained in $(w-\epsilon,w]$? And why would that imply $f(c)\ne w$?

Comment: Who was invoking invariance of domain? I can't imagine how that could be relevant...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was thinking that since $f$ is clearly not onto $S^1$, it maps any $(a,b)$ into an arc which is homoeomorphic to an interval (composing for instance, with an appropriate branch of $\tan^{-1}$. Then one applies invariance of domain.

Comment: @Silent $(c-\delta,c]$ and $(c,c+\delta)$ are themselves connected and so must be mapped into arcs.

Comment: Since $f$ has domain all of $\mathbb R,$ if $f$ mapped any interval $(a,b): a,b\in \mathbb R$ onto $S^1$, then it can't be injective.

Comment: @Matematleta, thanks for that reply, but why those arcs should be disjoint?

Comment: @Silent because $f$ is injective.

Comment: I was forgetting that $f$ is injective, sorry.

Comment: @Matematleta, OMG! I am so sorry that I confused being disjoint with being somehow connected. I will be obliged if you clarify why both arcs disjoint implies $f(c)\ne w$.

Comment: @Matematleta What if $f((c-\delta,c]) = (w-\epsilon_1,w]$ and $f((c,c+\delta)) = (w-\epsilon,w-\epsilon_1]$?

Comment: $f((c-\delta,c))\subseteq (\eta,w]$ s.t. f(c)=w and $f((c,c+\delta)\subseteq (\epsilon_1,\eta)$ so $f$ is not continuous at $c$.

Comment: Exactly. I think you should incorporate this in your answer. Also, why do you mention in the beginning without proof that $f$ is not onto? Your proof for the openness of $f((a,b))$ actually shows that (for $(a,b) = \mathbb R$).

Comment: I think you need to know that $f$ is not onto beforehand for the proof to go through. But it's easy: if $f$ mapped $(a,b)\ \textit{onto}\  S^1$ then choosing any $x\notin (a,b)$ there is a $c\in (a,b)$ s.t. $f(c)=f(x)$ so $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @Matematleta How can you choose $x\notin (a,b)$ when $(a,b) = \mathbb R$?

Comment: @amsmath, he is talking about basis element. One of basis for $\Bbb R$ is $\{(a,b): a,b\in\Bbb R,  a<b\}$.

Comment: You want to show that $f$ is open. So you pick an open set $U$ and prove that $f(U)$ is open. If $U$ happens to be $\mathbb R$, you can take $any$ finite open interval $(a,b)$ and if $f((a,b)$ is open then so is $f(\mathbb R).$

Comment: @Matematleta What? I don't understand that reasoning. I'm talking about your claim in the *beginning* of your answer that $f$ is not surjective. This requires a proof! And BTW, $S^1$ is open.

Comment: @amsmath we are working in a finite interval $(a,b)$. If $f$ maps $(a,b)$ onto $S^1$, then pick any point $x$ not in $(a,b).$ Consider $f(x).$ Since $f((a,b))$ is $\textit{onto}\ S^1$ there is a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=f(x).$ But then $f$ is not injective-

Comment: @Matematleta Dude, please read my comments more carefully. Of course, a finite interval cannot be mapped onto $S^1$. I'm talking about $\mathbb R$. So, my question: why can't $\mathbb R$ be mapped onto $S^1$?

Comment: @amsmath how does the fact that $S^1$ is open come into this? In fact, $S^1$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2.$ Of course if you give it the subspace toplogy (which we do) then it is open (in itself) by definition.

Comment: Not saying that $f$ is not onto $S^1$. The fact that $f$ may or may not map $\mathbb R$ onto $S^1$ is irrelevant to my proof-

Comment: Ok, I see now. It turns out that I was actually the one who did not read carefully enough. I thought that in your answer you say that $f(\mathbb R)\neq S^1$. My apologies.

Comment: btw: there is no continuous bijection from $\mathbb R$ onto $S^1$.

Comment: @Matematleta I know. But still, I couldn't yet understand your reasoning for $f(\mathbb R)$ to be open. How does this follow from $f((a,b))$ being open for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b$?

Comment: @Matematleta I see now. It follows from $f(\mathbb R) = f(\bigcup_n(-n,n)) = \bigcup_nf((-n,n))$.

Comment: Pick any $z\in f(\mathbb R).$ There are $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ such that $c\in (a,b)$ and $f(c)=z.$ We have proved that $f((a,b))=V$ is open in $S^1$. So, $V\in f(\mathbb R)$ is an open set containing $z$ which is what we want

Comment: @Matematleta That's another way. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

The sort of argument the OP had in mind works with no problem if we know this (where $\Bbb T=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$):

> > **Main Lemma.** If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb T$ is continuous there exists a continuous $\theta:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $f(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}$.

(Note: When I wrote all this I was forgetting that $f$ is injective. That implies $f$ is not surjective, which makes the lemma completely trivial;  we an just let $\theta(t)=-i\log(f(t))$ for an appropriate branch of the logarithm in the plane. But the lemma is true without assuming $f$ is injective, and since this is an important fact we'll prove it for general continuous $f$.)

When I made a comment to this effect I was assuming that the lemma was something everybody knew. Evidently not. So:

**Proof 1.** This is clear from a little topology. The map $t\mapsto e^{it}$ is a *covering map* from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb T$; now since $\Bbb R$ is simply connected any continuous map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb T$ "lifts" through this covering map.

A slightly dodgier version of that argument in terms that may be more familiar to some readers:

**Proof 2.** Since $\Bbb R$ is simply connected and $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ is continuous and has no zero there exists a continuous branch of $\log(f)$ on $\Bbb R$.

**Comment.** Some readers are saying to themselves "we don't need no steenking covering maps". Yes you do need covering maps! For example, there are various results in elementary complex analysis that show simply connected domains have special properties. You do believe those results are things you need to know, and most of them are just covering-map arguments in disguise (see for example *Complex Made Simple*); they  make more sense if you look at them that way.

Or one can essentially include the covering-map argument without mentioning covering maps:

**Proof 3.** If $I\subset \Bbb R$ is an interval say $\theta:I\to\Bbb R$ is *acceptable* if $\theta $ is continuous and $f=e^{i\theta}$ on $I$.

First, it's clear that there exist *local* acceptable maps:

> > **Lemma 2.** If $t\in\Bbb R$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that there exists an acceptable  $\theta$ defined on  $I=(t-\delta,t+\delta)$.

**Proof.** Choose $\delta>0$ such that $f(I)\subset D(f(t),1)\subset \Bbb  C$. Let $L$ be a holomorphic branch of $\log z$ on $D(f(t),1)$, and let $\theta(s)=-iL(f(s))$.

And two local acceptable maps can be patched together:

> > **Lemma 3.** If $I_1$, $I_2$ are intervals and $\theta_j:I_j\to\Bbb R$ is acceptable then $\theta_2=\theta_1+2\pi k$ on $I_1\cap  I_2$; hence there exists an acceptable $\theta:I_1\cup I_2\to\Bbb R$.

**Proof.** $k=(\theta_2-\theta_1)/2\pi$ is a continuous integer-valued function on $I_1\cap I_2$, hence it is constant. Define $\theta:I_1\cup I_2\to\Bbb R$ by $$\theta(t)=\begin{cases}\theta_1(t),&(t\in I_1),
\\\theta_2(t)-2\pi k,&(t\in I_2).\end{cases}$$

**Third Proof of the  Main Lemma.** By compactness, Lemma 2 and Lemma  3 show that there exists an acceptable $\theta_k:[-k.k]\to\Bbb R$. Wlog $f(0)=1$ and $\theta_k(0)=0$; now it follows that $\theta_{k'}=\theta_k$ on $[-k'.k']\cap[-k,k]$...

**Or** if we assume $f$ is *continuously differentiable* we can give a proof using just calculus, no not-entirely-trivial topology:

**Proof 4 (Main Lemma).** Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable. Assume wlog that $f(0)=1$. Define $$L(t)=\int_0^t\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}\,ds.$$Then $f(0)=e^{L(0)}$ and $$\frac d{dt}\left( e^{-L(t)}f(t)\right)=0,$$so $e^{-L(t)}f(t)=1$.

(And $|e^L|=1$ shows that $L=i\theta$, $\theta\in\Bbb R$.)

**Note.** If you try to use the usual tricks (approximate identities/mollifiers) to derive the continuous case from the continuously differentiable case you may find it more convenient to prove an apparently stronger version of the lemma:

> > **Main Lemma.02.** If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is continuous then there exists a continuous $L:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ with $f=e^L$.

**Exercise.** Explain why that version is only *apparently* stronger.

Comment: Thanks for your work!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Professor Ullrich! I will read this after dinner.